# CSV input file format for a (Sparse) ARFF which has a relational attribute

Tags: csv, machine-learning, nlp, weka, arff

I want to convert the CSV file to ARFF format (using CSVToARFFConverter) before other processing in WEKA. 
My ARFF file is in the below format:

```
@relation Sample

 @attribute CLS string
 @attribute SCLS string
 @attribute key relational
   @attribute key1 string
   @attribute key2 string
   @attribute key3 string
 @end key
 @attribute class {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}


@data
{0 type, 1 beta, 2 "3 keyword1\nkeyword2\nkeyword3", -5}
{0 typeA, 1 gamma, 2 "3 keyword11\nkeyword21\nkeyword31", 0}
{0 typeB, 1 alpha, 2 "3 keyword21\nkeyword22\nkeyword23", 3}
```

What is the equivalent CSV representation of the above Sparse ARFF file? Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand exactly your question, but if you already have the arff file why do you need a csv input? just use the arff in weka.

The equivalent CSV representation could probably be one of these:

```
CLS, SCLS, key1, key2, key3, class
0 type, 1 beta, keyword1\n, keyword2\n, keyword3, -5
0 typeA, 1 gamma, keyword11\n, keyword21\n, keyword31, 0
0 typeB, 1 alpha, keyword21\n, keyword22\n, keyword23, 3
```

or

```
CLS, SCLS, key, key1, key2, key3, class
0 type, 1 beta, 2, keyword1\n, keyword2\n, keyword3, -5
0 typeA, 1 gamma, 2, keyword11\n, keyword21\n, keyword31, 0
0 typeB, 1 alpha, 2, keyword21\n, keyword22\n, keyword23, 3
```

or

```
CLS, SCLS, key, class
0 type, 1 beta, keyword1\n;keyword2\n;keyword3\n, -5
0 typeA, 1 gamma, keyword11\n;keyword21\n;keyword31\n, 0
0 typeB, 1 alpha, keyword21\n;keyword22\n;keyword23\n, 3
```

Read this about relations in csv

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#General_functionality

hope it helps you